# Filtering query based on the value in Formula field

Tags: formula, formula-field, query

I am trying to filter a query based on a value in the formula field ,which is in hyperlink format .When i try quering the formula field based on its value its not returning any results.Is there any other workaround.But i see its access as filterable in Salesforce schema.

Answer (score 2):

You must be doing something wrong in your query.

I have created a test1__c formula field(in hyperlink format) and its returning proper result.

here is my Soql

```
select id,name,test1__c from contact where test1__c like '%google%' limit 10
```

One more example:

```
select id,name,test1__c from contact where test1__c = 'https://www.google.co.in' limit 10
```

Comment: I dont want to use keyword like because it will return results like google,google+ ,Googleabc...... for the input google .I need exactly the one which is same as Input.Not like

Comment: above soql was just example. Use your logic to twist it as per your needs. Updated answer with one more example.